# Can't use `su` anymore nor use `sudo` after using `sudo apt-get upgrade` (Debian)

Tags: debian, sudo, su

I'm having an issue right now. To set the scene : I'm currently working on a V2 for a Rails project, with more recent versions, gems, features etc, working with Nginx and Docker. In order to make it work on the server which hosts the project, I had to upgrade some things here and there, and especially I had to run a `sudo apt-get upgrade`. And from here on, I've been totally unable to use `su` in order to switch to `root` user and manage my Nginx files (for example). The command gives me this :

```
-bash: su: command not found
```

And the huge problem is that I can't even use `sudo` to fix it since it asks me the password of the user I logged with via ssh, which is not in sudoers. So I have no way to use my `root` user anymore.

I tried to log directly on the server with the root user but the option is my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` doesn't allow me to do so :

```
ssh root@[SERVER_IP] -p [PORT]
Permission denied, please try again.
```

So it's an ever-ending loop where I need to use `su`, which is not available, I need `sudo` to fix it but I can't log as `root` etc etc

I specify that the server on which the project is hosted belongs to us. Maybe I haven't looked in the right places to find a solution, but I find it weird that I don't see much topics about it.

Do you have any hint about it please ?

Comment: Have you tried the full path : `/bin/su` or `/bin/sudo` ?

Comment: Does login from the console work?

Comment: It would be a huge security risk to allow root SSH access, now if your able to change that configuration, you could temporarily allow it but if you can’t then my suggestion is start to rebuild the server.

Comment: @doneal24 - I disagree.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for all your replies. I check and `su` isn't even in my `/usr/bin` directory. I contacted the hosting company and asked if they can either add my user to sudoers or enable back the `su` command. If they give me an other solution I'll detail it here. Have a great day